# Two popups when force quitting an application

Tags: 14.04, gnome, configuration

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 having /home in a separate encrypted partition. When Ubuntu 14.04 came out, I did a clean install, but without formatting my /home partition, thus, keeping all my settings, photos, videos etc.

Then, I realized that when a windows freezes, and I hit the close button, two "force quit" pop ups appear. The new, modal one, and the old one.

[image: Screenshot demonstrating the problem]

Any idea of how can I fix this and only show the new, modal one?

-------EDIT----------

After doing a bit of research, only to know if it's a system wide problem, or more of a user problem, I created a dummy user, and I switched to it. Then, I did the same process:

1. Start gedit via terminal using `$ gedit&`
2. `$ killall -STOP gedit` to stop gedit
3. When the app turns gray click in the close button.

Doing that in the dummy user the result is the expected one, as shown below.

[image: Screenshot of the expected result]